# Critroni new bug in Tor

Tags: security, abuse, malware

Security experts detected a new kind of Crypto ransomware that uses the Tor network to hide its antics. The so-called “Critroni” has been flogged on underground forums for a few weeks now and is currently being used by the Angler exploit kit. The most interesting thing is that it is the first crypto ransomware that uses the Tor network for command and control.

Is it still safe to use Tor? Is there an update to cure this?

Comment: Yes, all it's doing is using the Tor network to assist in masking their servers location.

Comment: That's not a bug. That's like saying the Internet has a bug because it allows people to send unwanted email.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug in Tor, it's a feature. It doesn't reduce Tor users' security, but rather is evidence of it. If there were an update that "cured" it, it would make Tor less safe for you to use.

[Paul Syverson observed on tor-talk](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-September/030097.html):

> Back in the ancient pre-Tor days, at the height of the crypto wars, Ian Goldberg asked me at Financial Crypto in 1998 why we created onion routing. Not entirely facetiously I told him that the fascinating technological problems and the potential to better protect people and their activities was nice, but the real attraction was to create a context where people who were sure they should hate each other were forced to collaborate.